# How to install arch linux packages with yaourt when invoked with docker build from Dockerfile?

Tags: virtualization, arch-linux, docker, packages, chroot

I am trying to build my own jira container using official [pritunl/archlinux](https://hub.docker.com/r/pritunl/archlinux/) image. I have already installed yaourt and committed that to rusk85/archbase. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
1: FROM rusk85/archbase
2: CMD /bin/bash
3: RUN yaourt -Sy --noconfirm atlassian-jira
```

This results in error:

```
Running makepkg as root is not allowed as it can cause permanent, catastrophic damage to your system.
```

Then I tried to add after line 2:

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash jira
USER jira
```

That in turn asks me for a password.
Another variant was to use this instead of USER jira:

```
RUN su jira
```

This also returns the first error. I then created a user jira, installed sudo, enabled all users of group wheel to execute any command w/o password and added jira to group wheel as well as assigning the password jira to the user jira. I committed those changes to my image and tried it again with:

```
FROM rusk85/archbase
CMD /bin/bash
USER jira # fixed: was docker before
RUN yaourt -Sy --noconfirm atlassian-jira
```

That again asks for the initial sudo password. 
I searched for this issue in all variants known to men and also looked at multiple Dockerfiles but my searches came back without any usable results and all Dockerfiles I looked at left me completley confused. I would appreciate a really simple example for how to get passed this. I apologize if this is a really trivial issue but I just started out with Docker and the knowledge I have of arch to date doesn't seem to quite cut it.

Comment: that looks like a very old image, have you updated all the packages inside?  have you installed the `base-devel` package group?

Comment: @quixotic: Sorry I stated the wrong repo. I am actually using the official(?) arch linux image which is `pritunl/archlinux`. Fixed that in my post. Yes I even had `yaourt` set up which depends on `base/devel` (partly afaik). **What has `base/devel` to do with my dilemma of being unable to install packages from a `Dockerfile` that require root in one way or another ?** Btw I created my own base image with alpine linux using their mini root filesystem version. Build my own nginx reverse proxy with that which works. See https://goo.gl/qCu7py and https://goo.gl/xoM5vJ. Still need an answer though.

Comment: i don't use yaourt so i'm guessing. i think `yaourt` will build you a new package every time you start that container; you may need to `RUN pacman -S base-devel` (or similar) first, if your image does not already include those packages.  the `makepkg` error you see may be an indication you need `fakeroot`, which is included in the base-devel packages.  `yaourt` itself does not seem to depend on base-devel packages to install, so just because you have it doesn't mean you have the others.

Comment: Well you are right I only had parts of devel installed and fakeroot is indeed missing. Haven't tried it out yet with fakeroot but from what I understand one of its use cases is building packages without elevated/root privileges. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, **[DO NOT USE YAOURT](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers#Comparison_table)**.

Then, let me quote the official Arch [makepkg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/makepkg#Usage) wiki page:

> Running `makepkg` itself as root is **[disallowed](https://lists.archlinux.org/pipermail/pacman-dev/2014-March/018911.html)**. Besides how a `PKGBUILD` may contain arbitrary commands, building as root is generally considered unsafe. Users who have no access to a regular user account should run `makepkg` as the **[nobody user](http://allanmcrae.com/2015/01/replacing-makepkg-asroot/)**.

So back to your issue, you should not try to do what you trying to do.

But if you still want to:

- You can install yaourt but can only install as **non-root** user.

or

- You can try *(at your own risk)* [Allan McRae](http://allanmcrae.com/2015/01/replacing-makepkg-asroot/)'s solution which is considered as a good explanation of a replacement of the old `makepkg --asroot` command.